# Add, Update, Delete datas on Table in DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sql-server-ce

i already add my datas on Table (using SqlCE on DataGrid) using this code:

```
private void btn_functions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conSTR = @"Data Source=C:\Users\Zet\DB\javascript_db.sdf";
            SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conSTR);

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Functions";
            connection.Open();

            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, connection);
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            //for datagridview for js
            dg_JS1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            connection.Close();
        }
```

(you can take a look here result: http://oi42.tinypic.com/30sc6qf.jpg)

problem was i dunno how can i add/edit/delete specific cell direct to datagrid itself . and save direct to my table in database .

sample scenario there will be 3buttons for add/edit/delete, then lets say i add text on a cell then when i press btn_Add, the data should add in datagrid and direct to table, if i press btn_Edit, all data i update should update from datagrid to db, and if delete, all data that i selected/ text in the cell will automatically deleted same as to table .

or other idea can be ...

any idea how can i do it?

thanks a lot in advance! more power!

Comment: You must use the DataTable and DataGrid the other way around. Bind the DataTable to a DataGrid, and when you change your DataTable it is reflected in the DataGrid.

Comment: how can i do that? sorry kinda confuse what your sayin @MikedeKlerk

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem without a Button. In the following code I´ll give you a example how the connection and the update works with a mysql-database (update in runtime):

**CODE**

```
DataTable dt = null;
DataGridView dgv1 = null;
```

If the form load you have to set your dt variable to a new datatable:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = new DataTable();



    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "select *from try.data ;";
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    dgv1 = new DataGridView();
    dgv1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dgv1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv_CellEndEdit);
    dgv1.CellValidating += new DataGridViewCellValidatingEventHandler(dgv_CellValidating);
    dgv1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    dgv1.DataSource = dt;

    this.Controls.Add(dgv1);
}
```

You have to set two events: CellValidating

```
private void dgv_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            dgv1.CancelEdit();
        }
    }
```

and the CellValidating Event:

```
private void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Eid"] + "";
        string col = dt.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ColumnName;
        string data = dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value + "";

        string sql = string.Format("UPDATE `try`.`data` SET `{0}` = '{1}' WHERE Eid = {2};", col, data, id);

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

This aktually works with MySql but in Sql are "Equal" components like the SqlConnection or the SqlCommand... I hope this solve you problem. Have a nice day!